# Check if Int `mod` every element of a list == 0

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a (Literate) Haskell code that bruteforces the lcm (least common multiple) of a list of Ints.

I already thought about a strategy, but I'm not that good with Haskell syntax and don't know a lot of functions.

This is the function so far:

```
> bruteforceLCM :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
> bruteforceLCM xs n = if EVERYELEMENTOFTHELIST `mod` n == 0
>                        then n
>                        else (bruteforceLCM xs (n+1))
```

Where xs is the list of all Ints and n is the current Int that gets checked for being the lcm.

The first call would be `bruteforceLCM xs 2`, because n=0 would be not divisible and n=1 would always return true, these cases are solved with pattern matching earlier.

What would I have to replace "EVERYELEMENTOFTHELIST" with to achieve my goal?

Greeting, Joe

EDIT: Here is the whole code now, thanks to dfeuer!

```
> bruteforceKGV :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
> bruteforceKGV xs n = if all p xs then n else (bruteforceKGV xs (n+1))
>   where p x = n `mod` x == 0
```

Comment: It does what? Where does this `n` come from?

Comment: Added an explanation for both arguments, thanks for pointing out I forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting out with

```
bruteforceLCM :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
bruteforceLCM xs n = if EVERYELEMENTOFTHELIST `mod` n == 0
                       then n
                       else (bruteforceLCM xs (n+1))
```

When you say `` EVERYELEMENTOFTHELIST `mod` n == 0 ``, what you really mean is "For each element, `x`, of `xs`, `` x `mod` n == 0 ``".

Let's write a predicate expressing what that says about an element of the list:

```
p x = x `mod` n == 0
```

Now we can use `all`, which takes our predicate and tells us if it's true for all elements of the list.

But now we might want to clean things up a bit at a higher level. Because Haskell is lazy, we don't need to be so explicit about the recursion. We can do something like this instead:

```
bfLCM xs = fromJust $ find SOMETHING [2..]
```

Unfortunately, running this leads to a lot of infinite loops, because your math actually turns out to be a little bit wrong. Can you figure out where your mistake is?

Comment: Shouldn't `p x = x `mod` n == 0` also give a "not in scope" error for n? And I'm sorry, but as a complete beginner I am having trouble with your last line of code. The $ is a dividing symbol between arguments that are meant to be in different brackets, right? Is this equivalent to `bfLCM xs = fromJust (find SOMETHING [2..])`? And if so, where do you specify if a number fits the scheme (in this case being a mod 0 of x)?

Comment: @JoeCocker, ``p x = x `mod` n == 0`` will give a "not in scope" error for `n`, yes, *unless* you put that definition in a place where `n` is in scope, using a `let` expression or a `where` clause. `$` is the function application operator, so `fromJust $ find SOMETHING [2..]` does indeed mean `fromJust (find SOMETHING [2..])`.

Comment: By the way, you can type backticks in inline code by using *double* backticks to surround that code.

Comment: Yeah I actually knew you could use backticks here to escape some characters, I just did not see I produced an imcomplete code in my last comment and time ran out to fix it. Anyway, I implemented the code using `if all p xs` and ``where p x = x `mod` n == 0`` and I ran into your predicted infinite loop while testing. Can you give any lead why this happens? From my point of view the math actually seemed fine, I check every whole number from 2 onwards until it fits the scheme ``[m] `mod` n == 0``, is there a logical mistake or just a wrong implementation?

Comment: Well actually my initial question was "How can I check if every element of a list mod n equals 0", which got solved by you right now, so I should ask for more help in a new thread according to the guidelines for asking questions. Thank you!

Comment: @JoeCocker, think about what LCM means again. You'll get there.

Comment: oh wow, i implemented a solution to find the smallest shared divisor if there exists one and go in an infinite loop if there is none! well, thank you for pointing that out, i think i wouldn't have seen such an obvious mistake because i was too sure with my code... so i'll just have to swap some things out now that i know how i can approach the problem

Comment: @JoeCocker, you only need to swap exactly two variables. Think about what divides what.

Comment: yes, I now swapped x and n in my where statement and changed it in my initial post. Interesting though that you get the least common divisor and least common multiple by just swapping out what divides what, I never thought of that by just looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

Can you write down a function `f :: Int -> Bool` that checks if an `Int` is 0 modulo n? I'll leave this first step to you.

So now you have a function `f :: Int -> Bool` and a list of `Int`s, and you want to see if `f x` is `True` for every `x` in the list. We [ask Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Int%20-%3E%20Bool%29%20-%3E%20[Int]%20-%3E%20Bool), and it tells us about [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:all). You'll use `f` as the first argument of `all` to do what you want.

Comment: To check if an Int modulo another Int (since both vary) would require me to give in both Ints as an input, which would make it `f :: Int -> Int -> Bool`. Can I handle that with `all`?

Comment: Sure. For ease of notation, let's say that the thing you mod by is the first argument to `f :: Int -> Int -> Bool`, i.e. that `f n m` checks if `m` is zero modulo `n` (however unpleasant that may be to read). Partial application means that `f n` is a new function with signature `Int -> Bool`. This is the function that checks if its (single!) argument is zero modulo n, and it (i.e. `f n`) is precisely the function you pass to `all`.

Comment: Trying to do that gives me a "not in scope" for m, which was kinda what I expected since I'm telling f to know n but not m while using both in `f n = m 'mod' n == 0`, how can I bypass that? Signature is `f :: Int -> Bool` now. I'M sorry for these basic questions, but I really don't understand where `all` would take the other Int from and how `f` could work alone.